# How do you leave a Guild in Elder Scrolls Online

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

How do you leave a guild in Elder Scrolls Online? If you are in multiple guilds how do you specify which one you would like to leave?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The option is a bit hidden; obviously so you don't do it by accident.

It's quite easy once you know it:

- Open the *Guild* with *G* (default keybind).
- Click on the name on the top left to make sure you've got the correct guild selected (since you can join up to 5 guilds at a time).
- Click on the **Members** tab.
- Locate your *own* entry in the members list.
- Right click your *own* entry and you should see the option to leave the guild.

Comment: Struggled with this myself, and just last night finally stumbled onto it.  Wish I'd seen your answer sooner :/

Answer (score 0):

There is now a Leave Guild button at the bottom of the screen (on PC).

1. Open the Guild screen with 'G'.
2. Select the guild you want to leave.
3. Press 'X'.

One note.  It seems if you leave items in the store when you leave the guild, you lose them, so be careful.